# Is it correct to say "A thread is dangling from the hem of your shorts. Cut it off"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Is it correct to say "**A thread is dangling from the hem of your shorts. Cut it off**" (see the above picture)?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. What do you think might be wrong with it? Are they someone else's shorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, but think how you might shorten the expression by taking advantage of context and dialogue.

Do you need the imperative "Cut it off" (could you let the other person decide how to deal with the thread, or change it to an offer "shall I get my scissors?")

Do you need "hem of..."  could you just say "shorts" Does "hem of" help the other person locate the thread? Is there a more useful way of identifying where the thread is.

It might be more natural to say "There's a thread dangling..." or "You've got a thread dangling..."